# Trying to use the value in one cell to populate a formula in another cell

Tags: excel

Does anyone know how to use the value of one cell to fill in a formula?

i.e.  My cell `y5` and cell `AA5` contain the numerical date value, and I want to place that value in my formula listed below:

```
=SUMIF(I:I,">=Y5",J:J)-SUMIF(I:I,">=aa5",J:J)
```

This is the completed formula if I type it in:

```
=SUMIF(I:I,">=41671",J:J)-SUMIF(I:I,">41698",J:J)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, not sure why you put them between quotes, because, well, quotes makes it a literal string and no substitution will be performed in the formula. Try this instead:

```
=SUMIF(I:I,">="&Y5,J:J)-SUMIF(I:I,">="&AA5,J:J)
```

The `&` is concatenating the operator to the substituted value.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it, and did it give you a specific error?  I know for a fact it can be done, and I think your formula is probably close.  In fact, I think your problem is just the placement of your quotes.  Try something like this:

```
=SUMIF(I:I,">="&Y5,J:J)-SUMIF(I:I,">="&AA5,J:J)
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked with the quotes and the &.  When I did it with my formula no error just didnt return a value.